# ant not found issue while adding android platform in window7

Tags: android, windows, cordova, ant, cordova-3

[image]Whenever I am trying to run the following command I am gettign the ant not installed error.

```
C:\MyApp\Android\MySpe\Audio>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\atulc\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\atulc\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:4
7:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
Error: C:\Users\atulc\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command
 failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\atulc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I have also updated my Environment variable accrodingly but still getting the above mentioned error:-

ANT_HOME : C:\ant
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\
and path variable as well..

Any help is really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your PATH environment variable.
If you already created the ANT_HOME environment variable, add this to your PATH:

```
PATH = "(current_path);%ANT_HOME%\bin"
```

[image: ANT_HOME]

[image: Path]

Comment: what is (current_path)? is it the value that is already there and you want me to append the rest?

Comment: This is what I have addedd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\;C:\Users\atulc\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Users\atulc\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Comment: well I just did what you have mentioned but still getting the same error.. :(

Comment: did you close and open the command prompt window in which you see this error ? just type ant to see if the program is found. If you have that problem from an IDE like eclipse, you need to restart it.

Comment: i just executed command echo %ANT_HOME% and it is returning right information as c:\ant. this is where my ant folder stored with lib and bin folder. let me restart my laptop..and see how it goes.

Comment: Guess what Man, restarting my PC did the trick. I would have kissed you. if you were here. Thanks Mate. really appreciate your time and help..Regards, AC